# How do you tokenize 1800Flowers?

Tags: lucene, solr

I have a field with the value 1800Flowers. When I index it, I want it tokenized into 1, 800, Flowers, 1800Flowers and then eventually n-grammed. 
Currently, I have written my own filterfactory to do it. However, I was wondering if Solr can do this with the existing Tokenizers & Filters. Anyone has any better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [PatternTokenizerFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory).

Comment: PatternTokenizer will possibly help me get 1, 800 and Flowers out of 1800Flowers, but I want the original term preserved too.

Comment: you can add an copyfield with different tokenizer